# Error in environment(formula) : argument "formula" is missing with no default

Tags: r, vgam

I'm using the vglm function of the VGAM package.

`m <- vglm(log(variable+1) ~ ., tobit(Lower=0), data = dat)`

I was able to run the code above without any issues previously, but I'm getting this error message.

> Error in environment(formula) : argument "formula" is missing, with no default

EDIT:

Also tried running this
`vglm(log(demand+1) ~ ., tobit(Lower=0), data = BOD)`

but I'm also getting the same error message

Comment: have you tried explicitly passing the argument? `vglm(formula = log...`

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example since when I try it with other data  `vglm(log(demand+1) ~ ., tobit(Lower=0), data = BOD)`  it does not produce any errors.  I used VGAM 1.1.16. and "R version 4.1.3 Patched (2022-03-10 r81883)"
 on Windows.

Comment: i tried passing the formula argument, i'm still getting the same error

Comment: @G.Grothendieck i tried running the same code vglm(log(demand+1) ~ ., tobit(Lower=0), data = BOD) but I get the same error that the formula is missing. I'm trying to reinstall the vgam package

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it unfortunately still doesn't work with the BOD data

Comment: Paste this `library(VGAM); vglm(log(demand+1) ~ ., tobit(Lower=0), data = BOD)` into https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yup it works, I think it may be my R environment, just not sure how to troubleshoot this

Comment: Start a fresh session and try it without loading anything prior to that.  Be sure that your .Rprofile file does not add anything.